# Populating a object array with user input. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, user-input

Im trying to complete these 2 objectives using C#. I missed the class explaining how to populate an array with an object so i dont really have a starting point how to do the second objective.

"1. Create a Student class with two fields, StudentName (string) and StudentNumber (int), the appropriate properties (i.e. get and set) and constructors (default and non-default). The student name will default to an empty string while the student number will default to -1.

1. Use the Student class to solve the following problem.
   Create a program that will allow a user to input up to 24 students into an array ensuring that the student number is exactly 5 digits long. Once all the students have been entered, allow the user to do sequential searches for students by either name or number. Display the full student name and number if found, or an error message if not. Allow the user to keep searching until they decide to quit."

The first part i got working and here is my Student Class:

```
class Student
{
    // fields
    private string _studentName;
    private int _studentNumber;

    // properties
    public string studentName
    {
        get
        {
            return _studentName;
        }
        set
        {
            studentName = value;
        }
    }
    public int studentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _studentNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            studentNumber = value;
        }
    }
    // constructors
        // default - no parameters
    public Student()
    {
        _studentName = "";
        _studentNumber = -1;
    }
        // non default - takes perameters
    public Student(string studentName, int studentNumber)
    {
        _studentName = studentName;
        _studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}
```

And here is my main program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ////////////// Question 1 ////////////////

        // create new student
        Student defaultStudent = new Student();
        // display student
        InputOutput.DisplayStudentInformation(defaultStudent);
        // keep console open
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now im running into the problem with the second part of the objective. I don't know how to use the Object(student) class to help me create a user entered array as i missed that particular lecture.

Im not asking for someone to do the whole assignment for me, i just don't know how to populate the array with a studentName and studentNumber with user input.

I am at my wits end trying to get a starting point here. Anyone?

Comment: So you want to create student array and then populate those instances?

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.ReadLine() to get input from console application. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx.

Once you have the name and number and have performed validations, create the student object and add to array

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
            string nameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            // alternative is to generate own student number
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
            string numberInput = Console.ReadLine();
            // perform validations then create Student                        
            int number;
            // check result of TryParse
            int.TryParse(numberInput, out number);            
            students.Add(new Student { Number = number, Name = nameInput });
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the quick reply. I will give this a try and update my status once I do so.

Comment: The question is asking me to complete this with an array. Is a list an acceptable replacement?

Comment: @user1884609 if you can accomplish the work with raymond's answer you can definitely figure out how to use above code with arrays I presume!

Comment: The above method with the list works until i input the number and the program shuts down in a stackoverflow x.x but im guessing that means there is something wrong with my object and not raymonds code lol.

Answer (score 0):

In the main method, you can create Student Object array.

```
Student[] ourStudents = new Student[24];   // declared an array of stduent objects
```

You can use a `For` loop to iterate to populate each student object using another array that may contain student number and name. Otherwise you can bind these objects to a Console input/Form Text Boxes :)

Manually filling up each object:

```
ourStduents[0].Number = 12345;
ourStudents[0].Name = "John Kent";
```

Please ignore the part of `Form` as you are doing all your work in console window.

```
for (int i = 0; i<24; i++) //just user the static array length
{
      myStudents[i].Number = Console.ReadLine();
      myStudents[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### ADDING MORE CODE TO EXPLAIN FURTHER AS PER OP'S COMMENTS

Assuming all works well in your Student Class, here goes the `main` Class.

```
using System;
namespace array_sample
{
    class StudentData
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex num = new Regex(@"^\d{5}$");
            Student[] ourStudents = new Student[24];   
            // declared an array of stduent objects 

            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your Student Number :");
                Match n = num.Match(Console.ReadLine());
                if (n.Value != "")
                {
                  ourStudents[i].Number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
                  // make sure to convert to integer

                  Console.WriteLine("Enter your Name :");
                  ourStudents[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); 
                }
                Else
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Number Can only be 5 digits");
                  if (i > 0)
                     {i = i - 1;}
                  else
                     {i = 0;}
                }

            } // end of input loop

            for(i=0; i<24; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number : " + ourStudents[i].Number +'\t' + "Name :"
                                  + ourStudents[i].Name);
            }// end of output loop

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }// end of class
} // end of namespace
```

Comment: In this approach you used ourStudents in the hard coding method, and myStudents in the user input method using the read line. Was this on purpose or a typo? Also on the second method how do you prompt the user for input? Doesn't a read line require some kind of input? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I have just shown you the two ways to set values for your Student object/s. One manually filling up. Two with prompting user to input via console window and saving them into each Student object as array iterates. How about I just put the entire main as an update to the question. May be you can try that out?

Comment: i have 6 errors that pop up trying this method. wont let me paste them all. have you tried including my object class when trying it?
Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 2 'Assignment7.Student' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'Assignment7.Student' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Look at the above assumption? And yourself said in your question that you only need a `lead guidance` not to do your assignment ;) I updated code adding static array length as 24. **User your Student objects property as you have defined then in your Student class.**

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah god dam lol thank you. for some reason i wasnt able to clue into that your Number and Name variable only had to be changed to my object variables. Im sorry if i come off arrogant or sound like im expecting you to do everything for me. This isnt an assignment worth any marks, i want to do this to have an understanding of the concept and a reference point in the future. I will update progress once i try this out!

Comment: Glad you got it. I was waiting for to at least notice my bold comment ;) I suggest you a nice C# material [HEAD FIRST C#](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/) AWESOME piece.

Comment: I will definitely give that a read, thank you. Im very green in programming so i appreciate you going out of your way. I understand what the code is trying to do but I encountered a few errors with the regex and match commands. (i have never even seen these before :P but i understand its intention)
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 3 The type or namespace name 'match' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).   Any hints?!

Comment: You can simply use everything `main` method onwards in your own programme. Regex restrict your input to be 5 digit number. Add Regex library class for it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308252

Comment: Im sorry but how do i add the library class?? Isnt it included with VisualStudio.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/UrXTJ.png) this link shows you a picture of the errors im seeing.

Comment: Do the comments and answer help you out? This is your learning process, read the errors and find answers.

Comment: to use a a class from another assembly, add the assembly as reference. Then you need to add a using statement to declare that you are using entities within a specific namespace

Comment: @Raymond I have mentioned those way before! To OP

Answer (score -1):

```
Import TerminalIO.*;
Import BreezySwing.*;

Insert Codes here 
Insert Hacks here
Insert JavaScript here
int CR;
CR=reader.readln("Import TerminalIO")
System.out.println(" +CR+ ")
```

Comment: Very amusing, but not terribly helpful. :)